# ggplot2: Set plot title inside scale function

Tags: r, ggplot2

The [ggtplot2 documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/#section-coordinate-systems) states that "`labs()` and `lims()` are convenient helpers for the most common adjustments to the labels and limits" which also includes the `ggtitle()` function (as far as I understand).

**Question**

Is it possible to set the plot title within a call to `scale_*()`? In other words, what is `ggtitle()` a convenience function for?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the plot title via `scale_`. You can set axis labels and legend labels inside `scale_` functions such that

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(wt, mpg, col=factor(cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Weight") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="Miles Per Gallon") +
  scale_color_discrete(name="# of Cylinders")
```

is the same as

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  aes(wt, mpg, col=factor(cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(
    x = "Weight",
    y = "Miles Per Gallon",
    color = "# of Cylinders",
  )
```

The definition of `ggtitle` is

```
ggtitle <- function (label, subtitle = waiver()) {
    labs(title = label, subtitle = subtitle)
}
```

so it's a convenience function for `labs()`. There is no scale for plot title since you cannot map your data to the plot title via aesthetics.